# Are wildcard SSL certificates supported across all browsers?

Tags: ssl-certificate

Does anyone know if a wildcard certificate is supported across all browsers: IE6, IE7, IE8, Firefox, Chrome and Safari?  If I were to access the following secured sites sharing one wildcard certificate across all browsers, I won't be prompted by the browser:

```
https://one.example.com
https://two.example.com
https://three.example.com
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, they will work in all browsers as long as you configure them properly.

Answer (score 1):

The three addresses you listed there will work with a certificate for ***.example.com**.  Be careful with other names you might add in the future if they have more words separated by periods.  The meaning of ***** for certificates is inconsistent between browsers.  Some will match anything, others will match only one word separated by periods.

```
https://one.example.com/        *.example.com    YES
https://two.example.com/        *.example.com    YES
https://www.one.example.com/    *.example.com    NO
https://www.two.example.com/    *.example.com    NO
```

Answer (score 0):

The cert usually isn't the problem, but the issuing CA. Nowadays any major SSL provider is going to be compatible with 99% of browsers.